# How to know a number's unit in Sass

Tags: sass

I would like to know a number's unit. Is it possible ?

For exemple, let's say we have `10px`, but we don't know it is in pixels. I would like to know my value's unit is `px`. How to write a function that would give me: `px` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [unit function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unit-instance_method).

From the above documentation:

> unit(100px) => "px"

If you have a pure number, e.g. `10`, then it does not have units. You could convert it to pixels by multiplying it by `1px`. [Understanding Sass Units](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sass-units/) might be of use to you.